# Recursive feature elimination (caret) with linear regression, how to disable intercept?

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-caret

I am using recursive feature elimination from the R package 'caret'
Linear regression works fine for my problem, therfore I am using functions = lmFuncs insinde my control function.
But I would like to test this setup again without an intercept, is this possible?

My current code:

```
control <- rfeControl(functions = lmFuncs
                      , verbose = FALSE
)

results <- rfe(df_train
               , df_train
               , rfeControl=control                           
)
```

I would also go for a custom function, but I do not know how.

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit:
I found the answer after having a deeper look into the caret package.**

lmFuncs without Intercept:

```
lmFuncs_wo_intercept <- list(
  summary = defaultSummary,
  fit = function(x, y, first, last, ...) {
    tmp <- if(is.data.frame(x)) x else as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    tmp$y <- y
    #lm(y~., data = tmp) #old
    lm(y~0+., data = tmp) #new
  },
  pred = function(object, x) {
    if(!is.data.frame(x)) x <- as.data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
    predict(object, x)
  },
  rank = function(object, x, y) {
    coefs <- abs(coef(object))
    #coefs <- coefs[names(coefs) != "(Intercept)"] # old
    coefs[is.na(coefs)] <- 0
    vimp <- data.frame(Overall = unname(coefs),
                       var = names(coefs))
    rownames(vimp) <- names(coefs)
    vimp <- vimp[order(vimp$Overall, decreasing = TRUE),, drop = FALSE]
    vimp
  },
  selectSize = pickSizeBest,
  selectVar = pickVars
)
```

Comment: Not including the intercept is a bad idea if you don't have strong convincing reasons (from science!) for this. There are good theoretical reasons for including an intercept in linear regression.

Answer (score 1):

lmFuncs is your linear regression? I this case you could try to fit a second linear regression without the intercept and then apply the feature elimination function